# sudo - ввод пароля root для выполнения команды

Tags: linux, root, sudo, su

Вот. У нас есть sudo, и у нас есть пользователь user.
Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе, например `sudo firefox`, нам надо было вводить пароль не user, а root?

По сути, можно ли сконфигурировать sudo так, чтобы он работал аналогично `su -c`? Нигде в сети не нашёл решения проблемы. `man` тоже не помог.

Comment: см. описание флагов [rootpw, targetpw и runaspw](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html) в `$ man 5 sudoers`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо, то что надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `/etc/sudoers` вставьте `Defaults rootpw`. 
Теперь `sudo` будет запрашивать пароль `root`